# 500 - An error has occurred – DB function reports no errors when adding new article in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I have an article that I want to publish on my Joomla! site. Every time I click apply or save. I get error `500 - An error has occurred! DB function reports no errors`. I have no idea why this error comes up, al I can think is that it's a server error.

I'm using TinyMCE to type articles together with Joomla! 1.5.11.

Updated: I turned on Maximum error reporting in Joomla! and in the article manager I tried to save the article and got these couple of errors. Please check screenshot

[image]

I tried adding

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('html_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
?>
```

at the top of the index.php pages for Joomla! but it does not show any errors. I checked the error logs on the server and also no errors come up.

I managed to publish the article via phpMyAdmin but then something else happens. I try to access to article from the front end, by clicking on the link to the article, but only a blank page comes up.

This is really weird, since the error log does not show any information. So I assume the error needs to be coming from Joomla!

This happens if I add a print_r($_POST) before `if (!$row->check()) {` on /administrator/components/com_content/controller.php (around line 693)

```
    Array
(
    [title] => Test.
    [state] => 0
    [alias] => test
    [frontpage] => 0
    [sectionid] => 10
    [catid] => 44
    [details] => Array
        (
            [created_by] => 62
            [created_by_alias] => 
            [access] => 0
            [created] => 2008-10-25 13:31:21
            [publish_up] => 2008-10-25 13:31:21
            [publish_down] => Never
        )

    [params] => Array
        (
            [show_title] => 
            [link_titles] => 
            [show_intro] => 
            [show_section] => 
            [link_section] => 
            [show_category] => 
            [link_category] => 
            [show_vote] => 
            [show_author] => 1
            [show_create_date] => 0
            [show_modify_date] => 0
            [show_pdf_icon] => 
            [show_print_icon] => 
            [show_email_icon] => 
            [language] => 
            [keyref] => 
            [readmore] => 
        )

    [meta] => Array
        (
            [description] => Test.
            [keywords] => Test
            [robots] => 
            [author] => Test
        )

    [id] => 58
    [cid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
        )

    [version] => 30
    [mask] => 0
    [option] => com_content
    [task] => apply
    [ac1e0853fb1b3f41730c0d52de89dab7] => 1
)
```

I had a bounty on this question, but the problem is still not resolved? [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239975/db-function-reports-no-errors-when-adding-new-article-in-joomla)

Any help will be appreciated!!

Here is a link to the article (text file with the source I got from TinyMCE) [Article](http://www.logiclink.co.za/article)

Comment: Note to readers: note the link at the bottom of this post for discussion so far. On this occasion I'm inclined to agree that a re-post is warranted... I've closed the **old** one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239975/db-function-reports-no-errors-when-adding-new-article-in-joomla) and saw that you can't post the article since it's confidential. Is it in "plain english", does it have html? Could you provide some more information? Joomla has some plugins that "filter" a lot of content. If you try to write "iframe" or "script" tags in Joomla TinyMCE it's going to be filtered, this is Joomla's way of providing security.

Did you try to disable TinyMCE filters? Go to "Plugin Manager", "Editor - TinyMCE 2.0" and change "Code cleanup" options to test.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't post the original article. It has TinyMCE generated html. I'll defnitely try and do what you told me

Comment: I switch code cleanup to on and error is still there, what do you mean by "Code cleanup" options to test?

Comment: Spoke with the editor of the article and he said I can give it to you guys

Comment: I deleted from chapter 1 to 4, and saved to test about the article size, and after deleting some chunk of text the article loads fine. (deleted from 5 to the last one too). I think nickf is correct about post_max_size. I can't comment in his message because of my low reputation score. Anyways, I found this link in joomla's official website, it may be useful. http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=199&t=308040

Comment: Did you try the suhosin fix presented in http://forum.codecall.net/blogs/jordan/288-suhosin-request-post-get-character-length-limit-max_value_length.html?

Comment: I tried the suhosin fix, added the lines in the .htaccess file but that did not fix the problem. I don't have shell access to the server or access to the php.ini file. I know mod_security is installed on the machine, but can't do anything about that since the host won't disable it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your POST array, it looks like the body text of your post isn't being sent. This would suggest it's a problem on the front end. Can you check the `name` of the HTML element where you are typing the body text? If you could edit and show us the relevant parts of the HTML form that would help too.

---

**edit:** ok, that article you linked to is almost 150,000 bytes, so it might be that it's choking on it. If this is a once-off article that you probably won't have to edit too much, I'd recommend putting in some dummy text and then going into your database using phpMyAdmin or something and editing the text in the `jos_content` table. The `introtext` and `fulltext` columns are defined as `MEDIUMTEXT` so they should be able to hold up to about 16MB without hassle.

If writing and/or editing articles of this size is something you'll be doing often (and hence, don't want to go into the DB each time), then perhaps you'll have to look at the maximum post size allowed.

Comment: <textarea id="text" name="text" > is where I type the body text. Smaller articles publish as normal.

Comment: how long are these articles? how many characters are you typing?

Comment: I edited the post and added a link to the article, I got the HTML code from tinyMCE and save it in a text file for you guys to have a look at

Comment: This is a once of article, going to follow your advise

Comment: Tried your solution, when I manually add the content in phpMyAdmin, it saves successfully but when I try to view the article in the front end it gives me a blank screen

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur when you use Firefox.

Try to reproduce using IE.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following task

"""you can ask to your hosting provider to disable the function suhosin in php.ini. When this function is enable, is not possible to save large posts."""".

Shailedner Ahuja

My Web Developer
http://www.mywebdeveloper.in

Answer (score 0):

Your article text is too big . The table might not be finding space to save this big . I would like suggest you to use the [LONGTEXT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)

datatype. Check if it works for you .